# Direct access to chunk with code of restricted page in NextJS

Tags: security, authentication, session, next.js, chunks

Is it safe that the NextJs server returns chunks via a direct link, even when the user is not logged in?

For example, I deployed the application with iron session [like this](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session/tree/dab76011ee9951b358db5e7d80dad45cb5453043/examples/next.js-typescript), logged in and received a direct link to the chunk with restricted page source code (it looks like

> http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/profile-ssr-dd88f1f8754f9903.js

in this case).

Now I can open it in any other browser without a session.
Can an attacker brute-force the prefix in this way and see, for example, what my admin page looks like? Is there a way to protect source code with restricted access or may be this is not a problem for some reason?

Comment: I am facing a the same problem. Did you find a solution to this? Preferably I would like to restrict access to page code on both an authenticated and authorised basis.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can add an auth check with [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) on `_next/static` although I haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

This still has no answers yet, the middlewares will block needed code for the whole app to work.